MAUI .NET 8 on Android -Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3'
I have created a new MAUI .NET 8 project and migrated the Xamarin forms project code. When I tried to run the project with the Android device in Visual Studio 2022 (windows), which threw the exception below,
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found.

This happens when trying to open a database connection.
I am using the package below for the SQLite connection,
<PackageReference Include="Mono.Data.Sqlite" Version="1.0.61" />

Note: This exception happening only on Android, It's working properly in iOS.
Please help us to resolve this issue.

I confirm I am also getting this.

May be check this out https://blog.stackademic.com/sqlite-database-with-your-net-maui-apps-e77c2f3c767f
